# Update form fields after form submitted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have no problem with submitting form data through AJAX, and display all that data in a separate div.

But how do I update the form itself with some new info based on server response?

In my case I have:

1. a form with many inputs, including a group of checkboxes
2. data from form is collected (with JQuery serialize) and sent to php script through Ajax.
3. I need to set a specific color for text near a selected checkbox.

I need to set that color not on client side, but based on server side script.

Please explain the correct logical process when need to update a form based on initial form data.

Comment: create a fiddle please on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you would send the data via AJAX (post/get) and then you would get the response from server script in plain text / json / xml format (your choice). In this case, if you need to return only color code, you can use plain text format. When you get the response, you can manipulate the data.

```
$.post("test.php", $('#form').serialize(),
function(returned_data_from_server_script) {
    $('some dom for color').css('color', returned_data_from_server_script);
});
```

Comment: you mean to manipulate the data by injecting a new JS code that will change whatever I need? Is this the only way?

Comment: you only need to return actual data that will be manipulated, in your case it's color (e.g. server script will return `#000`). And then with that data you can do whatever you want, in your case you would manipulate some DOM. Check the code example - there is a callback in all jquery ajax methods that has returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Server side, you can send back a json encoded variable like so.

```
echo json_encode( array('text_color', 'green') );
```

Then, on the client side, you can access this variable in the callback function.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax/test.html',
   dataType: 'json', 
   data: $('yourform').serialize(), 
   success: function(data) {
      var color = data.text_color; 
      $('yourElement').css('color', color); 
   }
});
```

Alternatively you could send back a class and add that class to the element.